# Duplicate rows oracle based on Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to duplicate a row based on the Parameter(Parameter is 999 by default) Column and ID. For example in the below sample, we have a threshold value `999`, If an ID has a row with `ParamComp = 999` and another row with `ParamComp <>999`, then for the row with `ParamComp <>999` we must create a new record with the ColVal of `ParamComp = 999`.

If an ID has rows with only `ParamComp = 999`, Just load it to the target directly (No duplication logic is needed).

Also If an ID has rows with only `ParamComp <> 999`, Just load it to the target directly (No duplication logic is needed)

**Input Data**

```
id  ParamComp   ColVal 
1   999         a
1   80          b
2   999         c
3   85          d
```

**Target Data**

```
id  ParamComp   ColVal  
1   999         a
1   80          b
1   80          a
2   999         c
3   85          d
```

Comment: I don't think your sample data follows the rules you have specified.  If so, then `id = 1` would have two rows with 999.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: When you say you want to "duplicate a column" you mean a row, correct? I don't see any additional columns created. Then: if you create a new row based on an existing one, but the ParamComp value is different, then it's not even a "duplicate". And in the title: a relational database has "rows" rather than "records."

Comment: @GordonLinoff For an ID, 999 is the value to be compared, Based on the ColVal of 999 other rows are duplicated -(In the case if an ID has ParamComp as '999' and a non 999 value).

Comment: @mathguy I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Gordon's answer (which may or may not be faster) is to do a partial cross join on a two-row dummy "table", like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 999 paramcomp, 'a' colval FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 ID, 80 paramcomp, 'b' colval FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 999 paramcomp, 'c' colval FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 85 paramcomp, 'd' colval FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 999 paramcomp, 'e' colval FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 75 paramcomp, 'f' colval FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 70 paramcomp, 'g' colval FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your table; see SQL below:
SELECT yt.ID,
       yt.paramcomp,
       case WHEN dummy.id = 1 THEN yt.colval
            WHEN dummy.id = 2 THEN yt.paramcomp_999_colval
       END colval
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               paramcomp,
               colval,
               MAX(CASE WHEN paramcomp = 999 THEN colval END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) paramcomp_999_colval
        FROM   your_table) yt
       INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy ON dummy.id = 1 -- ensures every yt row is returned
                                                   OR (dummy.id = 2
                                                       AND paramcomp_999_colval IS NOT NULL
                                                       AND yt.paramcomp != 999) -- returns an extra row if the 999 paramcomp row exists but the current row isn't 999
ORDER BY yt.ID, yt.paramcomp DESC, yt.colval;

        ID  PARAMCOMP COLVAL
---------- ---------- ------
         1        999 a
         1         80 b
         1         80 a
         2        999 c
         3         85 d
         4        999 e
         4         75 e
         4         75 f
         4         70 g
         4         70 e
```

This assumes that there is only ever one 999 paramcomp row per id (e.g. a unique constraint on (id, paramcomp) exists).

You'd have to test this and Gordon's answer to see which is most performant against your data.

---

ETA: here's a fixed version of Gordon's answer for you to compare with:

```
select id, paramcomp, colval
from your_table
union all
select id, paramcomp, paramcomp_999_colval colval
from (select yt.*, MAX(CASE WHEN paramcomp = 999 THEN colval END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) paramcomp_999_colval
      from your_table yt
     ) t
where paramcomp_999_colval IS NOT NULL and paramcomp <> 999
ORDER BY ID, paramcomp DESC, colval;
```

---

ETA2: More explanation of the use of the dummy table:

If you wanted to duplicate all rows in your table, you would do a cross join to a table/subquery that has two rows, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table yt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy;

        ID  PARAMCOMP COLVAL         ID
---------- ---------- ------ ----------
         1        999 a               1
         1         80 b               1
         2        999 c               1
         3         85 d               1
         4        999 e               1
         4         75 f               1
         4         70 g               1
         1        999 a               2
         1         80 b               2
         2        999 c               2
         3         85 d               2
         4        999 e               2
         4         75 f               2
         4         70 g               2
```

However, you don't always want the duplicate row to appear, so you need to do an inner join that's a bit selective. I'll break down the inner join in my initial answer so you can hopefully see what it's doing a bit better.

First, here's the part of the join that ensures that each row in your_table is returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table yt
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy ON dummy.id = 1;

        ID  PARAMCOMP COLVAL         ID
---------- ---------- ------ ----------
         1        999 a               1
         1         80 b               1
         2        999 c               1
         3         85 d               1
         4        999 e               1
         4         75 f               1
         4         70 g               1
```

Next, here's the part of the join that ensures the selective joining

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table yt
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID FROM dual) dummy ON dummy.id = 2
                                            AND yt.paramcomp != 999;

        ID  PARAMCOMP COLVAL         ID
---------- ---------- ------ ----------
         1         80 b               2
         3         85 d               2
         4         75 f               2
         4         70 g               2
```

You can see with this second part that we still get the id = 3 row, which we don't want. So, in my final answer above, I found out what the colval of the paramcomp = 999 row was and returned that for all rows, using a conditional max analytic function. Then, I added that into the 2nd join condition part to only return rows that had a 999 colval (if they don't have a value, then we assume that the 999 row doesn't exist). This does assume that the colval will always be present for the 999 row.

Comment: Gordon's answer was not giving the desired output, It was duplicating the record with 999 itself and copying colval of non 999 record to it. Your answer is Working d gives me desired output. Do we have any workaround to correct Gordon's answer, so that I could compare the performance.

Comment: Why we are using dummy table with ids 1 and 2. Can you help?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a working version of Gordon's answer.

Comment: I've also updated my answer to include a more detailed explanation of the dummy table usage. If you still don't understand, I suggest you break the query down and have a play around for yourself, e.g. commenting out bits of the join conditions etc, to see what it's doing.

Comment: @Boniest - Suppose if I need to remove the row with Paramcomp = '999', Only for the rows which are duplicated, how can I do that? From the above result set I want to omit { 1,999,a} and {4,999,e}.I

Comment: You'd need to use a conditional analytic function to check for rows in the partition (aka group) that aren't paramcomp = 999, then you'd include that check in the join to dummy.id = 1 section. Try to work it out for yourself and if you get stuck, please raise a new question.

Comment: When you say 'conditional analytic function' Do I have to rank the '999' rows?

Comment: If you look in my initial solution, you will see that in the yt subquery I select `MAX(CASE WHEN paramcomp = 999 THEN colval END) OVER ...`. The presence of the `OVER` clause indicates that it's an analytic function. The CASE statement inside the `MAX()` indicates that it's conditional. In your case, you need to check that there is at least one row that doesn't have a paramcomp = 999. Then you can add that into the join condition in the relevant place.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that 999 is the maximum value for `paramcomp`, then an analytic function and `union all` can solve the problem.  Following the rules you specify in the text this would be:

```
select id, paramcomp, colval
from t
union all
select id, 999 as paramcomp, colval
from (select t.*, max(paramcomp) over (partition by id) as max_paramcomp
      from t
     ) t
where max_paramcomp = 999 and paramcomp <> 999;
```

This is easily modified for a simple variant of the rules.

Comment: In this table we have only '999' as the threshold. Also I don't want the 999 row to get duplicated,