# Conditional Analytical function oralce

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been using a Conditional analytical function,

```
 MAX(CASE WHEN col1= 999 THEN col2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) new_col
```

This returns only one value, for the below scenario.

```
   id       col1 col2
    1        999 a
    1        999 x
    1        999 y
    1         80 b
```

ie,.

```
new_col
      y
```

How can I return `a,y and x` in the output, using analytical function?
i.e. like this using any other analytical function

```
new_col
     x
     y
     b
```

Note: This is an extension to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437823/duplicate-rows-oracle-based-on-column)

Edit:

Desired Output:

```
       id       col1 new_col
        1         80 a
        1         80 x
        1         80 y
        1         80 b
```

Comment: Can you show us full SQL that doesn't return all rows while using window function? Data provided is not enough to notice problem.
EDIT: I suppose asking for full result table would be better. Need to see desired id, col1, col2 and new_col

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437823/duplicate-rows-oracle-based-on-column - In this question I have given the input set.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński - To that if I add a new row `1 999 x`, it is not getting duplicated with `80`

Comment: I still don't understand what your desired result is. You only provided one column in your question, but I think there should be 4. Maybe answer by Gordon works for you.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Gordons answer is a good solution. But I want the values in separate rows. `LISTAGG` is concatenating the result in to a single column

Comment: So you want all rows and columns but the 999 replaced by the max of the rest values in `col1`? And nothing changed in any other column?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, Also I want to get it by `partition by ID.` It si not necessary for taking `max`

Comment: `SELECT id, CASE WHEN col1 = 999 THEN MAX(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY id) ELSE col1 END AS col1, col2 FROM tablename;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `listagg()`:

```
LISTAGG(CASE WHEN col1= 999 THEN col2 END, ',')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) new_col
```